# MySQL InnoDB CASCADE?

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, innodb, cascade

I am starting to experiment with using InnoDB in web applications.  I've setup some tables with a foreign key, but they are not behaving as expected. 
Here are my table CREATE statements:

```
CREATE TABLE sections ( 
    section_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    title       VARCHAR(30), 
    created_at  int(10) NOT NULL, 
    updated_at  int(10) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(section_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE pages ( 
    page_id       INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    section_idfk  INT NOT NULL, 

    PRIMARY KEY(page_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(section_idfk) REFERENCES sections(section_id) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The tables create ok and I can populate them with data, however, I was expecting any changes I made to the Sections table to have an effect on the corresponding rows in the Pages table.  I tried changing the ID of a section and also deleting a section entirely.  In both cases, the Pages table was unaffected.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, this works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I quickly put together two similar tables in the MySQL Query Browser with the following definitions:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`sections`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`sections` (
  `section_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`section_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`.`pages`;
CREATE TABLE  `test`.`pages` (
  `page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `section_idfk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`page_id`),
  KEY `section_idfk` (`section_idfk`),
  CONSTRAINT `section_idfk` FOREIGN KEY (`section_idfk`) REFERENCES `sections` (`section_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Not exactly the same as the ones you posted, but close enough.

I insert into sections a row.
I add a row with a matching section_id into the pages table.
Then I do a DELETE FROM sections; and it deletes from pages as well.

Works just fine.

edit - I entered your creates and it works fine too.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm actually trying to do this from a php script, so I guess there's some kind of error in the SQL it's outputting.  Seems odd that it still creates any tables at all though.  I've echoed the output and it is identical to that above as far as I can see.