# Deleting multiple rows from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
`MEMBERS`
with
`NAME` varchar(24) UNIQUE KEY

`LAST_LOGGED_IN` int(11) - It is a timestamp!
```

---

```
`HOMES`
with
`OWNER` varchar(24)
```

---

```
`CARS`
with
`OWNER` varchar(24)
```

---

I use InnoDB for these tables, now my actual question is: **How do I remove rows within all the tables if the UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-`MEMBERS`.`LAST_LOGGED_IN` > 864000?**

I'm trying to remove inactive members' rows, and this is the hardest thing yet. I have about 40K rows, and increasing. I clean it regularly with `DELETE FROM MEMBERS WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-LAST_LOGGED_IN> 864000`

Any of your help would be extremely grateful! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already removed rows from the `MEMBERS` table, and you want to remove the rows from the other two tables where the value of the `OWNER` column does not match a `NAME` value from any row in the `MEMBERS` table:

```
DELETE h.*
  FROM `HOMES` h
  LEFT
  JOIN `MEMBERS` m 
    ON m.`NAME` = h.`OWNER`
 WHERE m.`NAME` IS NULL

DELETE c.*
  FROM `CARS` c
  LEFT
  JOIN `MEMBERS` m 
    ON m.`NAME` = c.`OWNER`
 WHERE m.`NAME` IS NULL
```

(N.B. these statements will also remove rows from the `HOMES` and `CARS` tables the `OWNER` column as a NULL value.)

I strongly recommend you to run a test of these statements using a SELECT before you run the DELETE.  (Replace the keyword DELETE with the keyword SELECT, i.e.

```
-- DELETE h.*
SELECT h.*
  FROM `HOMES` h
  LEFT
  JOIN `MEMBERS` m 
    ON m.`NAME` = h.`OWNER`
 WHERE m.`NAME` IS NULL
```

---

Going forward, if you want to keep these tables "in sync", you may consider defining FOREIGN KEY constraints with the ON CASCADE DELETE option.

Or, you can use a DELETE statement that removes rows from all three tables:

```
DELETE m.*, h.*, c.*
  FROM `MEMBERS` m
  LEFT
  JOIN `HOMES` h
    ON h.`OWNER` = m.`NAME`
  LEFT
  JOIN `CARS` c
    ON c.`OWNER` = m.`NAME`
 WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-m.`LAST_LOGGED_IN` > 864000
```

(N.B. the predicate there cannot make use of an index on the `LAST_LOGGED_IN` column. An equivalent predicate with a reference to the "bare" column will be able to use an index.

```
WHERE m.`LAST_LOGGED_IN` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-864000
```

or an equivalent:

```
WHERE m.`LAST_LOGGED_IN` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

For best performance, you would need indexes on both `HOMES` and `CARS` with a leading column of `OWNER`, e.g.

```
... ON `HOMES` (`OWNER`)
... ON `CARS` (`OWNER`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use InnoDB so I had to look it up, but it does appear to support Referential Integrity.  If you set relationships and then turn on ON DELETE CASCADE, the database itself will enforce the rules... i.e., when you delete a Member, the DBMS will take care of deleting the associated Homes and Cars.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578217/mysql-innodb-cascade) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855831/innodb-cascade-on-delete-and-update), they might help.

Comment: There are likely existing "orphan" rows in HOMES and CARS (given that the OP is already running deletes on the MEMBERS tables. In order to define a foreign key constraint (for InnoDB), the existing "orphan" rows in the child tables (orphaned by previous deletes from the parent) will need to be deleted, or have the member_id column set to NULL.